# Monogjs with chained dbname

Tags: mongodb, express

i'm new to all that Express stuff.
In my application i need one  users collection and a few members collection (one for each communitee).
I'm working with mongojs anrd it's great except when i want to use chained db name like:
db.kbz01.members

i get an error :

var members = db.kbz01.members;

```
                  ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined

in the mongo shell i can work with this kind of names no problems.
can you help?

Comment: Follow through the tutorials: http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html. The shell has lots of convenience features that don't exist in any mongodb driver.

Answer (score 0):

Use mongoose - npm install mongoose, mongoose = require('mongoose');
Documentation for mongoose here - http://mongoosejs.com/